# Does Kafka consumer api provide a way for you to search for partition number of a topic with key?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm working with a topic that have many messages.  Kafka is scale horizontally.  As a result, when they spread out to multiple processes, only 1 will work with the specific key.  The rest are not related and should stop the processing.

Is there a way from the client API to hash the partition number from the key?  With the partition number, we can stop the other processor from wasting cycle and start processing other events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so clear what you are trying to achieve here but let me explain how it works and maybe we'll find an answer.
I guess that your topic has N partitions, you are sending messages from producers specifying a key for each message and you are using the default partitioner. In this scenario, all messages with same key will reach the same partition and using the default partitioner it means that such a partition is defined by the hash of the key (then module the partitions number). On the consumer side you could have more consumers in the same consumer group so the N partitions are assigned to different consumers of the group; that's true that a consumer will be in charge of process the messages with same key because they'll be always in the same partition. It's also true that if a rebalancing happens (i.e. a consumer leaves the group or a new one is added), it can happen that the consumer for that key will change. In any case you can know the partition not from the key but the ConsumerRecord class which exposes it when the message is consumed. Furthermore, when the consumer subscribes to the topic you can provide and implementation of the ConsumerRebalanceListener interface in order to know which partitions are revoked/assigned to each consumer.
Otherwise, you could trying to use a custom partitioner so that giving a key, you have a different algorithm from the default one for defining the destination partition; in this case giving the key, you know the partition on the consumer side.
Btw as I said it's more an explanation than a real answer to your question. Maybe you could clarify a little bit ?

Comment: First off, thanks for your help.  What I am asking is if there is a method as following: `int partition = consumer.getPartition("key", "topic")` so you can get the partition number and start using the old static assignment api: `consumer.assign(Collections.singleton(new TopicPartition('topic', thePartitionNumberFromBefore)`.

Comment: Andras Beni have helped me to resolve this issue.  You can check the following:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201801.mbox/%3CCAOoS0_oqA-E6-vFQYdrgZ0Zcxokq6__oVAeQAEN%2BwSG2Cznf7g%40mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: And I solved it by getting the partition number from the context.getPartition() of Kafka stream AbstractProcessor because the triggering event of the processor is having the same key as the other topic.  Hence they share the same hashed partition when they are both using the same PartitionStrategy.

Comment: happy to help but it was not so clear that you were using Kafka Streams